# How to gain access to KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to save a string of user inputs to a file in a windows runtime app. However I'm getting the error `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. How do I gain access to this Library?

```
    static private async Task WriteDataToFileAsync(string fileName, string content)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);

        var folder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;

        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);


        using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            await s.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like the question has anything to do with wpf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Documents library" capability in Visual Studio 2013 has been removed since it is only available for Windows Store Company accounts. Without this capability you will get "Access is denied".

For more information, read here: http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2013/07/05/documents-library-capability-winrt/

Comment: And yet Microsoft's docs continue to show examples using it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-listing-files-and-folders
Microsoft needs to clean that up.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, notice under 'Extensions' I specify the file type I want to access (.txt) and then under 'Capabilities' I have added 'documentsLibrary'.

Then to actually write or access a file from there, something like this.

```
 var file = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync("myFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, data);
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest">
  <Identity Name="testapp" Publisher="CN=test.test" Version="1.5.0.3" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>test.MetroApp</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>test.test</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>6.3.0</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.0</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="test.MetroApp.App">
      <m2:VisualElements DisplayName="test.MetroApp" Square150x150Logo="Assets\test.png" Square30x30Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="test.MetroApp" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646">
        <m2:SplashScreen Image="Assets\test.scale-620.png" BackgroundColor="#464646" />
        <m2:InitialRotationPreference>
          <m2:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
        </m2:InitialRotationPreference>
      </m2:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <FileTypeAssociation Name="1">
            <DisplayName>AccessTXT</DisplayName>
            <SupportedFileTypes>
              <FileType>.txt</FileType>
            </SupportedFileTypes>
          </FileTypeAssociation>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
    <Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work in a Windows 10 app and I find nothing that gives access to documentsLibrary. The internetClient line is fine but musicLibrary and documentsLibrary won't build unless declared as <uap:Capability Name=...  But attempting to access documentsLibrary causes a runtime exception. Instead of manually editing, loading package,appxManifest in Visual Studio will give you a GUI interface to edit it.

Comment: Agreed @ChocoBilly. Did you find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary.aspx) "your app must use the File Type Association declaration in the app manifest file to explicitly declare what file types (extensions) will be accessed or created in the Documents library".