# UnauthorizedAccessException while attempting to create folder in documents (Universal Windows Platform)

Tags: uwp, runtime-error, windows-10-iot-core, create-directory

Trying to create folder into default user's document directory. and getting exception and no directory creating.
I also added Package.appxmanigest>Declerations>FileOpenPicker and FileSavePicker. Im newbie in this platform.where am I during wrong ?
(test is in x86 debug mode windows platform. somehow await line don't generate any error and cant debug the step next line. but this is another story)
also in appxmanifest >capabilities I see Pictures Library,MusicLibrary, but not documentsLibrary!?

somehow can generate files in LocalFolder.Path but I want it in documents directory.

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            //var doc = Windows.Storage.UserDataPaths.GetDefault().Documents;

            var dir_defaultdoc=CreateDefaultFolder();

        }

        private async Task<string> CreateDefaultFolder()
        {
            StorageFolder newfolder = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("MyApp1");
            return newfolder.Path;
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to gain access to KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681192/how-to-gain-access-to-knownfolders-documentslibrary)

Comment: the link you gave says ""Documents library" capability in Visual Studio 2013 has been removed " but not completely correct. now I can access. by the following lines in appxmanifest

Comment: it says it is removed VS does not mean it is removed from the platform.

Answer (score 0):

uap prefix is the key I just found accidently.

```
 <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
        <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
        <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
      </Capabilities>
```

somehow this fixed problem.

Comment: Do not use this. Use FolderPicker to gain access as documentation says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations